# Заполнение значений столбца с условием

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, обработка-данных

Есть фрейм со временем посещений пользователями ресурса.

Как заполнить колонку `visit`, считая все посещения одним пользователем внутри суток одним и тем же визитом?

Для примера заполнил колонку 'exmp_visit' вручную:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame([['user1', '2020-12-25 14:34:00',1],
                    ['user1', '2020-12-25 14:35:00',1],
                    ['user1', '2020-12-25 14:36:00',1],
                    ['user1', '2020-12-25 15:20:00',1],
                    ['user1', '2020-12-25 15:21:00',1],
                    ['user1', '2020-12-27 10:10:00',2],
                    ['user1', '2020-12-27 10:11:00',2],
                    ['user1', '2020-12-28 20:45:00',3],
                    ['user1', '2020-12-30 20:46:00',4]], columns=['name', 'visit_time', 'exmp_visit'])
df['visit_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['visit_time'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df["visit"]= df.groupby([df["visit_time"].dt.date, df["name"]]).grouper.group_info[0]+1
```

```
    name          visit_time  exmp_visit  visit
0  user1 2020-12-25 14:34:00           1      1
1  user1 2020-12-25 14:35:00           1      1
2  user1 2020-12-25 14:36:00           1      1
3  user1 2020-12-25 15:20:00           1      1
4  user1 2020-12-25 15:21:00           1      1
5  user1 2020-12-27 10:10:00           2      2
6  user1 2020-12-27 10:11:00           2      2
7  user1 2020-12-28 20:45:00           3      3
8  user1 2020-12-30 20:46:00           4      4
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df["visit"] = (df
               .groupby(pd.Grouper(key="visit_time", freq="D"))
               .ngroup()
               .diff()
               .fillna(0)
               .ne(0)
               .cumsum()+1)
```

результат:

```
In [45]: df
Out[45]: 
    name          visit_time  exmp_visit  visit
0  user1 2020-12-25 14:34:00           1      1
1  user1 2020-12-25 14:35:00           1      1
2  user1 2020-12-25 14:36:00           1      1
3  user1 2020-12-25 15:20:00           1      1
4  user1 2020-12-25 15:21:00           1      1
5  user1 2020-12-27 10:10:00           2      2
6  user1 2020-12-27 10:11:00           2      2
7  user1 2020-12-28 20:45:00           3      3
8  user1 2020-12-30 20:46:00           4      4
```

PS  немного корявенько получилось -  попробую сделать элегантнее...